# make_tape_recovery: is possible to do the same on linux?

Tags: linux, backup

On hpux,i use a fantastic tool from ignite-ux

```
make_tape_recovery -x inc_entire=vg00 -A -v -m pax -E
```

With this i make and image on tape,and even if VG00 is corrupted and or unavaliable,or something delete entire / it can recover simply inserting
a tape and boot from tape,after boot without touch nothing it restore the entire VG is possible also to make a net image instead of tape.
The question is: exist something like this for linux?A tool wich create a bootable and complete system image,starting from tape o network.
I know exist ignite-ux for linux,but is a commercial product and i know also
exist kickstart,but is specific for redhat.